# how to change UIWebView Tap events

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, uiactionsheet

How Can I change the `UIWebView` `tap` action Controls.like when I `tap and hold` on some link in `UIWebView` ..it opens a `UIActionSheet` with three options `open` `copy` `add to reading list` ...I need to change this `UIActionsheet` controls like ..I need to add one more button into this ...how to do that...how to disable this and add new `UIActionSheet` according to my choice...

[image]

**code**

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
NSURL *requestURL = [ request URL];

if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)
{
    // Call your custom actionsheet and use the requestURL to do what you want :)


    UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Contextual Menu"
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                         destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [sheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Save Page as Bookmark"];
    [sheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Open Page in Safari"];

    [sheet showInView:webView];
    return NO;
}

return YES;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

[webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]]];

webview.delegate=self;

}



- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet
clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {


if (buttonIndex == actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex) { return; }
switch (buttonIndex) {
    case 0:
    {
        NSLog(@"Item A Selected");
   NSLog(@"reg%@", request);

          NSURL *requestURL = [request URL];
        [webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:requestURL]];



        break;
    }
    case 1:
    {
        NSLog(@"Item B Selected");


        break;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: @AsifHabib just I have given a `UIWebView` with loading nsurl `google` to it...I just want to know how to change the tap events

Comment: did u find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this , catch a tap on link and use your actionsheet then

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 
{
    NSURL *requestURL = [ request URL];

    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)
    {
        // Call your custom actionsheet and use the requestURL to do what you want :)
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


     webview.delegate=self;
     [webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]]];



}
```