# UIWebView -> "Add to Reading list is not displaying"

Tags: ios, ipad, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` and I open a website in it. The website contains lot of hyperlinks.  I get an action sheet when I long-press it in Safari:  *Add to Reading list*, *Copy* and *Open* are displaying.  However in my UIWebView *Add to Reading list* is not displaying (below 6.1).

Comment: You'll need to create that for your webView.. You aren't using safari in your app...

Comment: Yes, i think its a bug of ios. In 6.1 Add to Reading list is displaying on UIWebview. but when click on it, nothing will happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add that option programmatically yourself. Also note that you cannot access Safari's Reading List programmatically.

For doing this, you would need to add an [UIActionSheet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/) to your view and display it when a link is tapped in your UIWebView.

For your reference have a look at this question: [how to change UIWebView Tap events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577454/how-to-change-uiwebview-tap-events)

Comment: Thankyou for your reply, above 6.0 simulator its working well,i don't know, why its only working in above 6.0 simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I solved above problem. I customized the contextual menu of UIWebView,

.

[Sample application for customize the contextual menu of UIWebView](https://github.com/sylverb/CIALBrowser)